# Can't specify include tags when using set Tag in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using data driven tests and setting the tags as part of the data.  Below is the simplified code:

```
*** Settings ***

Test Template    TN Lookup

*** Testcases ***
Testa    Hi    TC-1
         Bye   TC-2

*** Keywords ***
TN Lookup
    [Arguments]    ${text}    @{tags}
    Set tags    @{tags}
    Log to console     ${text}
```

Yet when I run the command:
`robot -i TC-1 filename.robot`

Both test cases run.  How can I specify which tags to run when using set Tags keyword or does this not work?

Answer (score 3):

The `-i` flag is only processed at the start of the test run and is only influenced by tags present before the tests run. Once the tests start running, you can't change what will or won't be run.